# Is Plone's Dexterity able to be programmed to use a database?

Tags: python, security, plone, dexterity

http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/advanced/permissions.html

> In the documentation, I see this,
>
> Note All permissions need to be defined before the  line in configure.zcml. Otherwise, you may get errors
>   trying to use the permission with a grok.require() directive. The
>   `permissions.zcml` file looks like this:
>
> ```
> <configure
>     xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
>     i18n_domain="example.conference">
>
>     <permission
>         id="example.conference.AddSession"
>         title="example.conference: Add session"
>         />
>
>     <permission
>         id="example.conference.ModifyTrack"
>         title="example.conference: Modify track"
>         />
>
> </configure>
> ```
>
> New permissions are granted to the Manager role only by default. To
>   set a different default, we can use the rolemap.xml GenericSetup
>   import step, which maps permissions to roles at the site root.
>
> In `profiles/default/rolemap.xml`, we have the following:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <rolemap>
>   <permissions>
>     <permission name="example.conference: Add session" acquire="True">
>       <role name="Owner"/>
>       <role name="Manager"/>
>       <role name="Member"/>
>       <role name="Contributor"/>
>     </permission>
>     <permission name="example.conference: Modify track" acquire="True">
>       <role name="Manager"/>
>       <role name="Reviewer"/>
>     </permission>
>   </permissions>
> </rolemap>
> ```
>
> Note This file uses the Zope 2 permission title instead of the shorter
>   Zope 3 permission id."

Can Plone's Dexterity be programmed to use a database?  What if I had thousands of users?  That's a lot of xml files to keep up with, when I have it in Active Directory already, or a MySQL database.  I want to keep buttons and other webpage items from being displayed based upon their security.  Dexterity appears to do that.

Thanks.

EDIT:  Thank you for clearing up my confusion between users and roles, as the users are kept in a repository like an LDAP server.

Am I correct that after I have my roles and users set up that all I have to do is wrap my html thusly (after defining the Python code as below):

"As an example, let’s display a message on the view of a Session type if the user has the cmf.RequestReview permission. In session.py, we update the View class with the following (same page),

```
from zope.security import checkPermission

class View(dexterity.DisplayForm):
    grok.context(ISession)
    grok.require('zope2.View')

    def canRequestReview(self):
        return checkPermission('cmf.RequestReview', self.context)
```

And in the session_templates/view.pt template, we add:

```
<div class="discreet"
     tal:condition="view/canRequestReview"
     i18n:translate="suggest_review">
    Please submit this for review.
</div>
```

"

Comment: You are misunderstanding how roles and permissions work. Roles are *not* individual users, they are specific roles a user can 'play'.

Comment: A user can be a manager, and a reviewer, and a contributor, for example.

Comment: You can see them as groups of permissions, grouped by the type of task you need to perform.

Comment: This all has nothing to do with how users are stored. Plone.org stores user accounts in an LDAP server, for example.

Comment: Are all the roles in the database unless I want to customize them?  Do I have to use the xml files for anything?

Comment: The XML files are *one* method to configure and register the roles your system knows about. Roles are stored in the ZODB object database. See http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/Security.html for an overview of how all this works.